# Проблема с созданием диаграммы базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

На узле "Диаграммы базы данных" кликаю ПКМ, выбираю "Создать диаграмму базы данных", возникает ошибка "Индекс находится вне границ массива". Работаю в ms sql server 2017, скажите в чем может быть проблема? Это лабораторная работа, делал всё по гайду, один в один.

Comment: Говорится о некой проблеме, но даже нет того, от чего можно отталкиваться. Приложите хоть скрины какие-то...

Comment: В mssql диаграммы часто глючат. Попробуйте скачать dbforge studio, там хорошо все строится.

Comment: Sql Server - это СУБД. Она никакие диаграмма сама по себе не строит. Очевидно, вы используете какую-то оболочку для работы с ней. Например, Management Studio. Укажите её.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй перезапустить sql server 2017. У меня помогло.